# Bluescreen when i restart windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I've recently upgraded from windows 7 to 10 using windows tool to upgrade, and I have a problem when I restart my PC for any reason it hang for a long time and at the end I get the new blue screen which start collecting info and at the end restart my PC.

How can i fix it ?

Edit : 
I have an hp Pro book 4530s ,i have no antivirus (i know what i am doing ) 
With windows 10 professional version 
I should also mention that i have a problem with my USB modem which won't eject when i unplug it and i can't get it to work until i restart my PC (this is where i found the problem )

This [zip](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=15C45DCB839212E5!354&authkey=!AFoxlYwSk8L-GrI&ithint=file%2Crar) file contain 2 dmp files of the last 2 crashes

And this is the report generated by blue screen view

```
    ==================================================
Dump File         : 113015-49281-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 30/11/2015 12:23:51
Bug Check String  : DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000009f
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000004
Parameter 2       : 00000000`0000012c
Parameter 3       : ffffe001`78ea7800
Parameter 4       : ffffd000`7df3f9b0
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+151656
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 10.0.10240.16590 (th1_st1.151104-1714)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+151656
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\113015-49281-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 557 552
Dump File Time    : 30/11/2015 12:25:44
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 112915-21734-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 29/11/2015 21:32:54
Bug Check String  : DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000009f
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000004
Parameter 2       : 00000000`0000012c
Parameter 3       : ffffe001`db6b9040
Parameter 4       : ffffd000`2a53f9b0
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+151656
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 10.0.10240.16590 (th1_st1.151104-1714)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+151656
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\112915-21734-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 557 048
Dump File Time    : 29/11/2015 21:34:22
==================================================
```

Comment: Can you add more info like exact versions,What was the method for updating? What is your PC specifications?

Comment: You need to provide us specific information about the BSOD.  Start by supplying the .dmp file, use BlueScreenViewer to indicate which drivers were loaded, and use Windbg  with `!analyze -v` to provide a verbose analyze of the problem.  Update your question to include this information.

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\WINDOWS\Minidump (as zip on OneDrive and post a link here).

Comment: @magicandre1981 done,sorry i forget to add the link before

Comment: is the issue fixed? Have you updated the drivers?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yeah,i updated the drivers and i still have the same issue

Comment: remove them and also try the 1511 ISO

Answer (score 0):

ok, the drivers ewusbwwan.sys (Huawei driver) and NetBalancer driver nbdrv.sys seem to cause it.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000004, The power transition timed out waiting to synchronize with the Pnp
    subsystem.
Arg2: 000000000000012c, Timeout in seconds.
Arg3: ffffe00178ea7800, The thread currently holding on to the Pnp lock.
Arg4: ffffd0007df3f9b0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_PNP on Win7 and higher

Debugging Details:
------------------

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KiSwapContext
01 nt!KiSwapThread
02 nt!KiCommitThreadWait
03 nt!KeDelayExecutionThread
04 nbdrv
05 0x0
06 0x0


BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_4_ewusbwwan_IMAGE_usbccgp.sys

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_4_ewusbwwan_IMAGE_usbccgp.sys

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  150709-1700

BUILDLAB_STR:  th1

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10240.16384.amd64fre.th1.150709-1700

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_4_ewusbwwan_image_usbccgp.sys


    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nbdrv.sys
    Image name: nbdrv.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Apr 19 21:13:24 2013 (51719754)

    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ewusbwwan.sys
    Image name: ewusbwwan.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Mar 21 02:57:34 2013 (514A690E)
```

So the crash is network related. remove all 3rd party tools which install network drivers (Netbalancer, AV suite, firewall, Virtual Machine tools like Vmware or VirtualBox), update the Huawei driver and try again.

The TH1 means you try to install the July 2015 version. [Get the 1511 ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench), mount it in Win7, run setup.exe and select "upgrade" to go to the November 2015 version of Windows 10.